# Could changing oracle version change the way order by workd?

Tags: sql, oracle

There has been an update of oracle from 10g to 12c where I work and now my sql query is working differently than expected. This is really minor, so it isn't a big problem, but I'm curious.

Previously after ordering by name I would have :

```
name  
aaa  
aab  
aa z
```

The space didn't seem to be taken in consideration when ordering alphabetically.

Now I have something like this :

```
Name  
aaa  
aa z  
aab
```

Any reason what could explain the comportement ?

Comment: Have the NLS setting changed? [This might be useful](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-B0971B89-63EF-409B-B14A-459B8211E764).

Comment: Could you run `select name, dump(name) from table` and append it's result to the question ?

Comment: @Alex Poole The NLS settings wasn't supposed to be changed, I'll try to find more info about this.

Comment: @krokodilko I don't think I can... There is confidential data

Comment: Is this an indexed column, and does the index appear in the explain plan?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are getting "aa z" sorted _between_ "aaa" and "aab"?  If so, can you ask your DBAs if anyone was doing anything using Locale Builder?  If not, I'd go with @krokodilko and `dump()` that value to make sure it is really a whitespace and not some special character that sorts like an "a" but that your client is not printing.

Answer (score 2):

When 11g came out, Oracle changed the behavior of `GROUP BY`. In 10g and earlier versions of Oracle `GROUP BY` implied `ORDER BY` - in other words, if you did a `GROUP BY` the results were ordered by the grouping fields. Starting with 11g this is no longer the case. The fix is to go in and add an `ORDER BY` everywhere that a `GROUP BY` appears.

Best of luck.

Comment: OP didn't say he's using `GROUP BY` but I'll bet $5 you've got the right answer.  smh.

Comment: I agree, he didn't, but that's the only thing I can remember that might have caused this.

Comment: Didn't that change between 9i and 10g? All too long ago...  But the question *suggests* (in title and text) that there iis already an explicit order-by clause,so this shouldn't matter.

Comment: @AlexPoole: meh. You might be right. That's what I get for trusting my memory. Now...the important question...what the heck did I have for lunch.....?

Comment: I experienced this migrating from 8i to 10g, but OP saying he has gone 10g to 12c, which is i thought it might not be this. But it is well worth the OP looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that during the upgrade the default **collation** was changed. You should ask your DBA for the current and previous default collation.

The collation setting regulates how strings of chars are sorted.

Also, I think I remember that the collation can be set per-table too to avoid using the default one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In 12.2, collation can be set per column.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - [it's in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-2AC4EE67-D3C0-4E26-87AD-2DA4584F874A) *8-)